# After checking all relevant Xcode settings, my executable still says "was compiled with optimization". Any suggestion?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am developing a macOS application in Objective-C and I am using [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013768-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) apple example as a base for my project. When I try to debug the privileged helper, it always says:

```
com.example.apple-samplecode.EBAS.HelperTool was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

I have checked the existing SA relevant questions but could not find a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It appears that dependencies can cause this kind of behavior. I am using the Qt frameworks in my Xcode Objective-C++ project. This could be the reason of the error. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will edit my question.